# How to handle mongodb "schema" change in production

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I use mongodb + node.js + mongoose.js ORM backend.

Let say I I have some nested array of object without _id field

```
mongoose.Schema({
  nested: [{
    _id: false, prop: 'string'
  }]
})
```

And then I want to ad _id field to all nested objectds, so the mongoose schema would be

```
mongoose.Schema({
  nested: [{
    prop: 'string'
  }]
})
```

Then I should run some script to modify production DB, right? What is the best way to handle such change? Which tool (or approach) is best to use to implement the change?

Comment: From the example you gave, it looks as if you want to remove the _id, instead of adding it. If you want to add an _id, how do you determine what each _id should be?

Comment: I don't get you. _id: false tells mongoose not to generate _id for objects described by schema, if I remove _id: false from schema description mongoose will create new docs with generated _id. What I'm askin is right way to populate all existing objects (wich doesn't have _id) with new _ids.

Comment: should the _ids be generated by the system, or by you?

Comment: I think by the system. I don't have any IDs, I just need that all objects to have _ids.

Comment: You need to write code to do this manually, element by element.

Comment: What is the best way to run this code? Make standalone node.js module that connects to db and make changed? What is the right approach to implement the change?

Comment: The best method here, since it seems like a one time command might be either, as you say a node.js module or a js script run in the MongoDB console on the master.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but MongoDb is a schema-less database. The collections do not have a defined schema, each object stored in the collection has its schema in the object itself. Saving the object will update its schema but maybe I am missing your point (not sure what you meant by "modify production DB").

Comment: mongoose.js introduces solid schemas. Besides I would read schemaless  as structure-flexible. You need a kind of shcema for any data structure as you need map in unknown city. By modify production  db i mean for example if you decide to remove some field from all documents in a collection.

Comment: just some plus: I would add a "schema_version" to the document to track schema changes

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One of the significant advantages of schema-less databases is that you don't have to update the entire database with new schema layouts. If some of the documents in the DB don't have particular information, then your code can do the appropriate thing instead, or elect to now do anything with that record.

Another option is to *lazily update* the documents as required - only when they are looked at again. In this instance, you might elect to have a per-record/document version flag - which initially may not even appear (and thus signify a 'version 0'). Even that is optional though. Instead, your database access code looks for data it requires, and if it does not exist, because it is new information, added after a code update, then it would fill in the results to the best of its ability.

For your example, converting an `_id:false` into a standard `MongoId` field, when the code is read (or written back after an update), and the `_id:false` is currently set, then make the change and write it only when it is absolutely required.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean with `_id:false`. I'm really interested. Can you explain it, please?

Comment: Ah, I haven't read the question text, sorry, it's not your fault. But the example with `_id:false` might be a bit misleading for the whole question. Would be nice to have an example which is better understandable for all and especially for those not using Mongoose.

Comment: How will this be with operations like adding a new index:
`patientSchema.index({ patientId: 1, institute: 1}, { unique: true })`, in dev I had to delete the old index without `{ unique: true }` to get it working

Answer (score 15):

You indeed have to write the script that will go over a collection and add a new field to each document. However exact way how you will do it depends on the size of your DB and performance of your storage system. Adding a field to the document will change its size and thus cause relocation in most of the cases. This operation has an impact on IO and also bounded by it. If your collection is just a few thousand documents, may be up to one hundred thousand, then you may just iterate over it in one loop because the whole collection probably fits into memory and all IO will happen afterward. However, if collection spans far beyond available memory, then the approach is more complicated. We usually follow next steps in production use of MongoDB:

- Open cursor with timeout=False
- Read a chunk of documents into memory
- Run update queries on these documents
- Sleep for some time to avoid overloading IO subsystem and hurting production application
- Repeat until done
- Close the cursor :)

Size of documents chunk and sleeping period must be determined experimentally. Usually, you want to avoid QR/QW in mongostats for the period of migration. For larger collections on slower drives (like EBS on Amazon) this IO-safe approach can take from hours to days.

Comment: Do you have a short code example for the cursor? I'm especially interested in JavaScript version, because I think it's not trivial, especially sleeping for some time and not getting parallel...

Comment: I don't have example for JavaScript, but in PyMongo driver disabling timeout for cursor done by simply passing timeout=False to find() method. I think that JavaScript driver will have something like this.

Comment: In this case, can I continue using `Mongoose` schemas? I asking it because Mongoose schemas self-update itself always we update the schema structure.

Answer (score 1):

Extending  @Michael Korbakov answer, I implemented his steps with `mongo` shell script (see [MongoDB Reference Manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/) about `mongo` shell scripts).

Important: as stated in [MongoDB Reference Manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/server-side-javascript/#running-js-files-via-a-mongo-shell-instance-on-the-server), running script on `mongo` shell can help performance because it reduces connection latency for each batch fetching and bulk execution.

A downside that should be considered is that `mongo` shell commands are always synchronous, but bulk execution already takes care of parallelism (for each chunk) for us so we're good for this use case.

code:

```
// constants
var sourceDbName = 'sourceDb';
var sourceCollectionName = 'sourceColl';
var destDbName = 'destdb';
var destCollectionName = 'destColl';
var bulkWriteChunckSize = 1000;
// for fetching, I figured 1000 for current bulkWrite, and +1000 ready for next bulkWrite
var batchSize = 2000;    
var sourceDb = db.getSiblingDB(sourceDbName);
var destDb = db.getSiblingDB(destDbName);

var start = new Date();

var cursor = sourceDb[sourceCollectionName].find({}).noCursorTimeout().batchSize(batchSize);

var currChunkSize = 0;
var bulk = destDb[destCollectionName].initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
cursor.forEach(function(doc) {
    currChunkSize++;
    bulk.insert({
        ...doc,
        newProperty: 'hello!',
    }); // can be changed for your need, if you want update instead

    if (currChunkSize === bulkWriteChunckSize) {
        bulk.execute();

        // each bulk.execute took for me 130ms, so i figured to wait the same time as well
        sleep(130);

        currChunkSize = 0;
        bulk = destDb[destCollectionName].initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    }
});

if (currChunkSize > 0) {
    bulk.execute();
    currChunkSize = 0;
}

var end = new Date();
print(end - start);

cursor.close();
```